# Mocking RestTemplate exchange returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I have looked at multiple posts here - [one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590669/mocking-resttemplate-exchange-always-returns-null) and tried multiple variations but still can't seem to be able to get a non-null value after mocking
`RestTemplate#exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)`.

I am not passing any `uriVariables`.

Here is my simplified source code:

```
Request request = new Request();
request.setDataId(1);
String query = "query ($ request:Request!)\n" + 
            "{\n" + 
            "    fetchData(request:$request)\n" + 
            "    {\n" + 
            "        planId\n" + 
            "    }\n" +
            " }\n";

RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody(query,Collections.singletonMap("request", 
            request));   
HttpEntity<RequestBody> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, createHttpHeaders());   
return restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/gql", HttpMethod.POST, request, 
JsonNode.class);

private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders()
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return headers;
}
```

The `RequestBody` class (uses `lombok`):

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RequestBody implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -203524485553511477L;
  private String query;
  private Map<String,Object> variables;
}
```

And the corresponding test code:

```
 @Mock
 private RestTemplate restTemplate;

 @Mock
 private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
 
 @InjectMocks
 private FetchDataService fetchDataService;
  
 @Test
 public void testFetchData() {
  String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/Data.json")));
     ObjectMapper testMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     JsonNode expectedResponse = testMapper.readTree(json);
 when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), 
             any(Class.class)))
     .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(expectedResponse, HttpStatus.OK));  
  ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = fetchDataService.getData();   
  }
```

`expectedResponse` is a `JsonNode` instance above. The problem is that `response` always returns a `null` body.

I am able to verify that the call does happen if I use this -

```
  Mockito.verify(restTemplate)
     .exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class));
```

I'm using junit 5, spring boot 2.6.7, jdk 11 if that matters.

Comment: Does your class `FetchDataService` has a constructor that take in parameter a RestTemplate object?

Comment: @HarryCoder Yes, this is what it looks like `public FetchDataService(RestTemplate restTemplate)`

Comment: Your simplified source code doesn't really help because you return the result of `restTemplate.exchange` from it, which is `ResponseEntity`. Whereas `fetchDataService.getData()` returns some `DataResponse`. As such, I can assume there is also some code between the `restTemplate.exchange` and `getData` calls. If you can just share that part it will be really helpful and the test misbehaviour will be easy to find.

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov good catch. I have updated the source code to reflect that I'm directly returning `ResponseEntity` but the body of that entity is `null` and doesn't have the `JsonNode` object that I expect it to have.

Comment: @linuxNoob given the `Mockito.verify(...)` doesn't throw and "the simplified" source code semantically and clearly represents the actual source code, I find it quite impossible for the `fetchDataService.getData()` to return `null`. Would you mind sharing the actual code of that method please?

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov added some more details, I'm not sure what else to add. The actual query is big with nested fields but I have simplified it. Also, have verified using POSTMAN that it actually does return data.

Comment: @linuxNoob can you also add  the `expectedResponse` value then? In the question you are saying "it's a JsonNode instance above" but there is no any JsonNode instance above there...

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov added. `Data.json` file just contains a sample json response and I can confirm that the `expectedResponse` is getting correctly populated. Also, I was incorrect/incomplete about the constructor earlier, this is what it looks like `public FetchDataService(RestTemplate restTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper)`

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov you were spot on the fact that the issue was with post response processing piece. Specifically, after reading through the JSON the code does this `objectMapper.treeToValue(responseNode, DataResponse.class);` and since my test has a mock version of `ObjectMapper` without mocking `treeToValue()` it returns `null`. I appreciate you taking time to look into the problem, I was looking at the wrong place. If you could make an answer I'll accept it and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author @linuxNoob has confirmed in our discussion in the comments, the issue was that `expectedResponse` didn't hold a proper `JsonNode` value. The reason for that is the `ObjectMapper` instance being mocked without any configuration to return something from its methods. So, any call was returning the default `null` value, i.e. `testMapper.readTree(json)` returns `null` that ends up being the value of the `ResponseEntity.body` through the `expectedResponse`.